# how to subtract the two input fields and get answer in input field

Tags: jquery, html

hi guys I want to subtract the fields with same class name but I get only one value in every answer filed help me please I am new to jquery .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td><input class="col-xs-4 a2" readonly type="number" id="form-field-first" value=""></td>
<td><input class="col-xs-4 b2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
</td>
<td>
<input class="col-xs-4 c2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="col-xs-4 a2" readonly type="number" id="form-field-first"  
value=""></td>
<td><input class="col-xs-4 b2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
</td>
<td>
<input class="col-xs-4 c2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="col-xs-4 a2" readonly type="number" id="form-field-first" 
value=""></td>
<td><input class="col-xs-4 b2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
</td>
<td>
<input class="col-xs-4 c2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

and this is my scripting code,kindely help me

```
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(function() {
 $(".a2, .b2").on("keydown keyup", sub);
 function sub() {
 $(".c2").val(Number($(".a2").val()) - Number($(".b2").val()));
 }
 });    

 });
 </script>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/ on the very first line: "Get the current value of the **first element** in the set of matched elements". If you want the values of all the fields with a given class, you'll have to loop through them. Even if .val() _did_ get all the values, your code wouldn't make much sense because you'd be trying to subtract one array from another array.

Comment: then what should i do with this code kindely help me more

Comment: Like I said, loop through the elements (e.g. all the ".a2" elements) and add their values together

Comment: can you post me a perfect code about the problem i will be very thank full to you please do it for me please

Comment: Actually I just realised you have got separate c2 fields as well. I think you want to calculate each row separately, yes? In which case the answer is slightly different. Wait a moment I will make an answer. I will also need to stop the a2 fields being readonly, otherwise it can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you need - it calculates each row separately, by identifying which textboxes belong together. It does this by using the enclosing table row as a bounding context, and find the correct elements within the row by their class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".a2, .b2").on("keydown keyup", function(event) {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr"); //we will use this to restrict scope to the current table row
    tr.find(".c2").val(Number(tr.find(".a2").val()) - Number(tr.find(".b2").val()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Val A: <input class="col-xs-4 a2" type="number" id="form-field-first" value=""></td>
    <td>Val B: <input class="col-xs-4 b2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
    <td>
      Result of A - B: <input class="col-xs-4 c2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Val A: <input class="col-xs-4 a2" type="number" id="form-field-first" value=""></td>
    <td>Val B: <input class="col-xs-4 b2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
    <td>
      Result of A - B: <input class="col-xs-4 c2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Val A: <input class="col-xs-4 a2" type="number" id="form-field-first" value=""></td>
    <td>Val B: <input class="col-xs-4 b2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
    <td>
      Result of A - B: <input class="col-xs-4 c2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** Base on your code this will not work because it is very complicated. why not try to do like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <input class="col-xs-4 a2" readonly type="number" id="form-field-first" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input class="col-xs-4 b2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="col-xs-4 c2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="col-xs-4 a2" readonly type="number" id="form-field-first" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="col-xs-4 b2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="col-xs-4 c2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="col-xs-4 a2" readonly type="number" id="form-field-first"value="">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="col-xs-4 b2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="col-xs-4 c2" type="number" id="form-field-first">
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Then on your `script` you can do just like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".b2").on('keypress', function(){
                var uiParent = $(this).closest('tr');

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        var b2 = uiParent.find(".b2").val();
                        var c2 = uiParent.find(".c2").val();

                        var total = b2 - c2;
                         console.log(total);

                        uiParent.find(".a2").val(total);
                    }, 2000);
            });

            $(".c2").on('keypress', function(){
                 var uiParent = $(this).closest('tr');

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        var c2 = uiParent.find(".c2").val();
                        var b2 = uiParent.find(".b2").val();

                        var total = b2 - c2;
                        console.log(total);

                        uiParent.find(".a2").val(total);
                    }, 2000);
            });
       });
```

I added `setTimeout()` function to wait until you finish entering numbers then after 2secs it will generate your answer...then I updated this code to make it flexible even if how many inputs in the table it will remain functional.

Hope it help!

Thanks

Comment: the problem with this, the way you have done the classes, is you have to add more code for every row in the table. Normally it's hard to predict how many rows will be in a table. since it usually depends on the contents of the database. So this solution is not really scalable.

Comment: this is better, and would work, although still too much code. And waiting two seconds won't guarantee the user has finished typing, and might just confuse users as to why it's slow to update.